# Header: Include Date Published and Date Modified

Tags: headers, date, post-meta

I'm trying to put the Date Published and Date Modified into the meta tags of the head of the header.php page - so far no luck.

This is what I currently have:

```
<meta name="date" content="<?php echo get_the_date( 'm-d-Y' ); ?>">
<meta name="revised" content="<?php echo the_modified_date( 'm-d-Y' ); ?>">
```

I've also left off the get_  with the_date but that didn't work either.
I've tried the_date.
I've tried without the echo.

I assume that since the header.php is pulled on each post and page, and that these dates are pulled in the Admin area that these should already in the Loop without needing to add to the functions.php. If I do need to add this can someone assist me with the code to put into the file and which file?

When I do an analysis at http://analyzer.metatags.org/ the page shows:

```
Status:         200 OK
Last update:    Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00
Web Server:     Apache
Content Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I really don't want to use a plugin. I'd rather learn how to do it.

I understand how to put this into a post or page but I can't get it right in the header.php.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if [is_singular](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) page/post and then use global $post to get the post ID outside the loop.
Also for the modified date you should use [get_the_modified_date](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_modified_date) instead because you're already echoing.

```
<?php if(is_singular()): ?>
    <?php global $post; ?>
    <meta name="date" content="<?php echo get_the_date( 'm-d-Y', $post->ID ); ?>">
    <meta name="revised" content="<?php echo get_the_modified_date( 'm-d-Y', $post->ID ); ?>">
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I tried this on a page and on a post and I still get: Last update:  Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00

Comment: And what do you have on the page source of those pages/posts? What do you have on those meta fields?

Comment: Yes, I inspected the head with the 'right click' and found that the dates were there. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Maybe it's just cache on metatags.org.

Comment: I think revised meta tag is not much used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889445/is-html-meta-name-revised-valid-or-even-used

Comment: Good it worked! If it was helpful, upvoting or marking answer as correct would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Thanks to dbeja's answer and suggestion to look at the source (of course), I found that using the code below did gave me the Publish Date and the Modified Date! 

     <meta name="date" content="<?php echo get_the_date( 'm-d-Y' ); ?>">
     <meta name="revised" content="<?php echo get_the_modified_date( 'm-d-Y'); ?>"> 

So, echo get_ is the way to go...I didn't have to add the $post->ID

Thank you, dbeja! ;]

Comment: I meant in the arrow/checkmark on the left side of the answer :) but thanks anyway

Comment: @learning2 Welcome to WPSE. Please consider marking this answer as accepted, if it solved your problem.